# How to add mhtml / mht file as relative path

Tags: css, internet-explorer, mhtml

I'm trying add external mhtml resource to css.
I have a css entry like this:

```
*background-image: url(mhtml:file://C:/folder/base64.mht!image1);
*background-image: url(mhtml:http://domain.com/base64.mht!image1);
```

works well, but I need to add base64.mht file as relative path.
Is it possible?

PS. This is trick to add css with base64 images to IE browser:
http://www.phpied.com/mhtml-when-you-need-data-uris-in-ie7-and-under/
Mayby is better way to add base64 images to css on IE7?

I will be grateful for any help.
Marcin

Answer (score 0):

Use an expression with `document.location` to reference a relative path:

```
background-image: expression("url(mhtml:" + document.location + "!polloloco)");
```